# Overwrite constructor in Java final class

Tags: java

I need to overwrite a constructor of a final class in Java. I know this isn't ideal, but it's unfortunately necessay. Is there any clever workaround to be able to achieve this? Specifically, there is a method that is called from inside the constructor in the final class, where I need to call with a different parameter (now it is called with a constant defined in the package of the final class).

Comment: Final classes can never be overridden, see the `String` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no good trick to circumvent final methods, but [there is a good trick against (static or not) final fields](http://zarnekow.blogspot.ch/2013/01/java-hacks-changing-final-fields.html)**. If changing that constant you talked about is an option, then you can do that by using reflection:

```
private static void setDefault(String newDefault) throws Exception {
  Field staticField = SomeFinalClass.class.getDeclaredField("CONSTANT");
  setValue(null, staticField, newDefault);
}

protected static void setValue(Object owner, Field field, Object value) throws Exception {
  makeModifiable(field);
  field.set(owner, value);
}

/**
 * Force the field to be modifiable and accessible.
 */
protected static void makeModifiable(Field nameField) throws Exception {
  nameField.setAccessible(true);
  int modifiers = nameField.getModifiers();
  Field modifierField = nameField.getClass().getDeclaredField("modifiers");
  modifiers = modifiers & ~Modifier.FINAL;
  modifierField.setAccessible(true);
  modifierField.setInt(nameField, modifiers);
}
```

}

*Note: obviously such a trick should be handled with care and avoided if there is a regular design pattern available.*

Answer (score 4):

It isn't just not ideal, it's not possible because it is final. Your best option would be to create a wrapper class:

```
  class WrapperClass {
    private FinalClass finalClass;

    public WrapperClass() {
      finalClass = new FinalClass();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
      finalClass.doStuff(); // <- this would be the final method you want to override

      // Do your own stuff
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! The thing is, from the constructor in the final class there is a call to a method. I need to overwrite so that the call is made with a different parameter (it's sent with a constant defined in the same package as the final class). I was a bit quick to write the question.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to override the method that is called and change your parameter, but all of this sounds to me like you're changing something that doesn't fit into your current design. I would advise you to review the design if possible and only continue with these workarounds if they are your last resort.

Answer (score 0):

If the class you want to modify has an interface, you can use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`:

```
public class ProxyTest {

  @Test
  public void proxy() throws Throwable {

    InvocationHandler handler = new MyInvocationHandler(new MyClass());
    MyInterface f = (MyInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(MyClass.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[] { MyInterface.class },
            handler);

    int result = f.test();

    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(20);
  }
}

class MyInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

  private MyInterface wrappedInstance;
  public MyInvocationHandler(MyInterface object) {
    this.wrappedInstance = object;
  }

  @Override
  public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {

    if(method.getName().equals("test")){
        return 20;
    } else {
        return method.invoke(this.wrappedInstance, args);
    }
  }
}
```